# Return extra info to a ODATA POST request in C#/WebAPI

Tags: c#, odata, webapi

We have a scenario when, after a record is posted, we want to return some extra (optional) info to the caller.

So that if they post a record to the API, the response is similar to this:

```
{
    "@extraInfo":"some extra info about the post result",
    "@odata.context":"serviceRoot/$metadata#People/$entity",
    "@odata.id":"serviceRoot/People('teresa')",
    "@odata.editLink":"serviceRoot/People('teresa')",
    "UserName":"teresa",
    "FirstName":"Teresa",
    "LastName":"Gilbert",
    "Emails":["teresa@example.com","teresa@contoso.com"],
    "AddressInfo":[{"Address":"1 Suffolk Ln.","City":{"CountryRegion":"United States","Name":"Boise","Region":"ID"}}],
    "Gender":"Female"
}
```

With enfasis in the @extraInfo tag.

We don't care about the actual name of the tag, or any specifics, but:

- We want to respect the OData standard so that any OData client can consume the service.
- But, for those clients that want to use it, an extra info message is returned (giving an explanation if some of the fields were updated by the API service).

One option that we've contemplated is to add a dummy property to the model and return the extra info there. Still, the message is more of a metadata to the call than an actual property, and we are looking for better solutions to this problem.

I'm sure that we are not the first ones that need to return some extra info with a POST or PUT message, so I'd like to know if there is a more standard/better/recommended way to do this, that does not require us to add dummy properties to the model.